Dual wheel rotor need part suggestions for rotor axle

I want to build this. One motor will drive two rotor shafts to spin two wire wheels. I can repurpose a wheel grinder motor. I'm having a hard time finding the rotating axles. Any recommendations on what I can salvage? Has to be long enough to extend past the motor, i'd clamp them down in place. I'll probably need some wheels to hold the belt in place. I'll make an outer cover for the wheels for safety.

axles are just shafts with bearings, and I suppose sheaves for a belt.  You will need a motor made for shaft outlets on both ends, and will need couplings to the driven shafts
